# Python Networkx: How to "redraw" graph after every iteration?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I am trying to simulate addition and removal of nodes and edges based on some conditions in **Networkx**. I am using `for` loops for this and `nx.MultiDiGraph()`.
A problem arises when I include the `nx.draw()` and `pylab.show()` methods in the loops. Although the graph/network is created without any problem in the first iteration, and then edges are added individually in the second, third ... so on iterations, the network does not "**redraw**" itself to show the removal of nodes and edges after an "`N`th". Also, after the second iteration (when the edges are added), duplicate edges are created again between the same nodes and in the output these edges keep "*darkening*" after every iteration showing a sort of blotch on the edges and nodes in the output, which I do not desire.
How can I "**redraw**" the graph after every loop iteration? Also, how can I remove the duplicate edges and nodes that are created after these iterations?
Thanks in advance for the help. (Using Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit VM and Python 2.7)

**UPDATE:**

Here is an example snippet of the code as specified by Reti43 (I want to show the network changing like a "movie" - with reference to my original question. My question can be understood much clearer with this example code) -

```
import networkx as nx
import pylab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from matplotlib.pyplot import pause
from matplotlib import pyplot
pylab.ion()

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

g = nx.MultiDiGraph()

def node():

    for epoch in range(1,9):
        print '------ iteration %d ---------' % epoch
        for nod1 in range(1,7):
            g.add_node(nod1)
            #for nod2 in range(1,7):   # this is how I originally create the graph
                #g.add_edge(nod1,nod2) # ''

        if epoch > 1:
            g.add_edge(1,2)
            g.add_edge(2,3)
            g.add_edge(5,4)
            g.add_edge(4,6)
            print(g.nodes())
            print(g.edges())

        if epoch > 5:
            g.remove_node(5)
            g.remove_edge(1,2)
            g.remove_edge(4,6)

        nx.draw(g, pos=nx.circular_layout(g), with_labels=True)
        #pylab.draw()
        pause(1)
        pylab.show()
#        plt.show()

def main():

    print '--------- Simulation ---------'
    node()
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the same edge twice in your graph object will insert a duplicate, which means it'll be considered twice for drawing, thereby increasing its thickness. You also have to call `plt.clf()` to clear the figure between steps, or else you'll get a superposition of everything drawn up to that point.

Regarding what edges to draw, you have two choices depending on how your program is set up.

**1. You can add/remove edges only as necessary.**

```
g = nx.MultiDiGraph()
g.add_nodes_from(range(1, 7))
pos = nx.circular_layout(g)

def node():
    for epoch in range(1, 9):
        if epoch == 2:
            g.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (2, 3), (5, 4), (4, 6)])
        if epoch == 6:
            g.remove_node(5)
            g.remove_edges_from([(1, 2), (4, 6)])

        plt.clf()
        plt.title('Iteration {}'.format(epoch))
        nx.draw(g, pos=pos, with_labels=True)
        plt.pause(1)
        plt.show()
```

You have to be careful here, because when you remove node 5, all edges related to that node are removed. So if you try to do `remove.edge(5, 4)` at the same time you'll get an error.

**2. You can use the `edgelist` argument.**

This states which edges will be drawn, even if they don't exist in your graph. Basically, when you have `edgelist=None`, the plot draws whatever is in `g.edges`.

```
def node():
    for epoch in range(1, 9):
        edges = []      
        if 1 < epoch <= 5:
            edges = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (5, 4), (4, 6)]
        elif epoch > 5:
            if 5 in g.nodes:
                g.remove_node(5)
            edges = [(2, 3)]

        plt.clf()
        plt.title('Iteration {}'.format(epoch))
        nx.draw(g, pos=pos, edgelist=edges, with_labels=True)
        plt.pause(1)
        plt.show()
```

Comment: Ah, I knew I was missing `plt.clf()` there. Thanks again @Reti43

Comment: Another curious question, how do I invert both the axes? Actually I use particular node positions and I see that `plt.clf()` inverts the axes and my network is an upside-down mirror image of what I want

Comment: I got the answer to my previous comment: I had to add `plt.gca().invert_yaxis and _xaxis()` after `plt.clf()`